Recursively include with EF Core 8?
I'm using EF Core 8.
I have a catalog system. It contains pages. Pages can have other pages as well as items. I need to load child pages recursively.
I have this
var page = await dbContext
                   .Set<CatalogPage>()
                   .Where(x => x.Id == eventParser.PageId)
                   .Include(c => c.Items)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.FurnitureItems)
                   .Include(c => c.Pages)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.Pages)
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

But it only loads one level deep.
This can keep going till the property CatalogPageId doesn't match a page (no parent), or in EF Core's case the opposite as it needs to load inner.
Here is my entity:
public class CatalogPage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public string? Caption { get; init; }
    public string? Layout { get; init; }
    public int? RoleId { get; init; }
    public int CatalogPageId { get; init; }
    public int OrderId { get; init; }
    public int IconId { get; init; }
    public ICollection<CatalogPage> Pages { get; init; } = [];
    public ICollection<CatalogItem> Items { get; init; } = [];
}

CatalogItem:
public class CatalogItem
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
    public int CostCredits { get; init; }
    public int CostPoints { get; init; }
    public ICollection<FurnitureItem> FurnitureItems { get; init; } = [];
    public string? MetaData { get; init; }
    public int Amount { get; init; }
    public int SellLimit { get; init; }
}


Can you clarify what database engine you are using this with? Depending on the underlying database, there might be other options that make sense here.

One way to achieve what you need is by forcing auto-inclusion of the collections in the configuration for your entities, by using the AutoInclude method.
For example, in your entitytype configuration fluent classes:
builder.Navigation(x => x.Pages).AutoInclude()

This would cause the property to always be expanded, which would then make it recursive by definition.
The caveat with this approach is that you do lose a bit of control over other situations when you don't want to include the relationship.

Hi thanks for answering but this produces System.InvalidOperationException: Cycle detected while auto-including navigations: 'CatalogPage.Pages'. To fix this issue, either don't configure at least one navigation in the cycle as auto included in OnModelCreating or call 'IgnoreAutoInclude' method on the query.

@user24419920 oh I see.... could you update your question with the model for the CatalogItem class as well?

@user24419920 additionally... can you test this out by making the CatalogPageId property nullable? You have "root" pages that have no parent, correct?

I've added the CatalogItem entity. Also yes, some pages are root so they don't belong to any other page. I've tried with a nullable CatalogPageId but same issue.
